# symfony2 how to create Image Entity shared between other entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entities

I'm using symfony 2 framework and i was wondering how can I create Image Entity that will be
shared between other entities.

Like:

```
1-entity  1->n image
2-entity  1->n image
...
n-entity  1->n image
```

I've found this topic: [use entity in multiple other entities in symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326682/use-entity-in-multiple-other-entities-in-symfony2)

But I'm wondering if it is a proper way to achive this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to share the entity, or do you want to have different entities for each relationship that are based on the same class?

Comment: @mattexx , different entities for each relationship. Let say I have movies and tv-series, all of them can have multiple images, and I want them to be stored in single table.